# flex3: Updating variable

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a public variable declared in mxml component. It's binded to UI element, so the UI element label, display it's changes. Now I need to be able to update the variable inside other separate as3 class, so the label will update itself...

Before this variable was declared in  main file of the Application, and I did something like
Application.application. = ;

Now I don't understand how to update it... (Because I had to refactor code and move it in separate mxml file)...

Comment: I'm not understanding your architecture from this post, please elaborate.  Parents can talk to children by setting properties or calling methods.  Children can talk to parents by dispatching events.  If your separate AS3 class is not a parent, or child, of the MXML component, then giving it access to update the variable breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cairngorm, you can get to the variables in the MXML file by passing the view object into the class:

MyMXMLClass(view).myVariable = newValue;

Really though, you should bind to a variable located somewhere where other source files can get to it easily. Say, create a separate class with a public static var in it that you bind to from both your MXML and your other ActionScript source files.